Mock GroupBy method with in-memory database
The following method works perfectly with SQL Server, no issues.
public async Task<IEnumerable<HashRecord>> GetLatestHashes(long jobId, CancellationToken token)
{
    var context = _contextFactory.Create();

    var hashes = await context.Set<PRH>()
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x => x.JobId == jobId)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Hash)
        .Select(g => new HashRecord
        {
            Hash = g.Key,
            Status = g.Any(x => x.Status == RPStatus.Successful) ? RPStatus.Successful :
                 g.Any(x => x.Status == RPStatus.Failed) ? RPStatus.Failed : RPStatus.Skipped
        })
        .ToArrayAsync(token);

    return hashes;
}

The PRH class is something like this:
public class PRH
{
    public long JobId { get; set; }

    public RPStatus Status { get; set; }

    public byte[] Hash { get; set; } = Array.Empty<byte>();
}

For this method, I have to create a unit test with an in-memory database but, since the GroupBy is working with the property Hash that is an array of bytes, two arrays with same values are different for GroupBy because it's comparing by reference.
What alternatives do you propose to face this issue with GroupBy?

Don't use Moq (or any other similar library) to test database queries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79094142/126014

I have to create a unit test with an in-memory database - localdb, then?

@flackoverstow it's a custom class for test that receives one argument like this "DbContextOptions options", where variable options is set with this "new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName).Options"

What is the underlying database type for the type that's being hashed? I'm trying to understand what is happening in the real database query.

Consider moving the boundary for your unit test up. This method:
// Note: "Async" suffix is highly recommended for async methods. 
//  It makes spotting and avoiding issues like missed awaits easier.
public async Task<IEnumerable<HashRecord>> GetLatestHashesAsync(long jobId, CancellationToken token)

... is basically wrapping the data access selection through EF similar to a Repository implementation. One reason to have a Repository wrapper like this is to facilitate unit testing. So mock this service/repository along the lines of:
mockHashRepository.Setup(x => x.GetLatestHashesAsync(jobId, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(mockedResults));`

We do not need to unit test that EF's Linq capabilities work as it's already tested and vetted.  If you want to assert that your Linq expressions actually return the correct results given a specific data state, that should be done with an integration test against a real data source set up with a known data state, and that data source should be using the exact same database provider that you will be using in production. As you've seen the in-memory data providers have limitations, and even using a data provider that does support grouping can allow other issues to creep through due to differences in behavior. (I.e. differing collation, etc.) Tests against a real database will take longer to set up, run, and tear down so these are run less frequently as integration tests rather than unit tests.
